# Chrome plugin - How to modify dynamically added content on a webpage from a content script

Tags: javascript

I've literally been stuck on this for 2 full days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to build a chrome plugin that will modify the text of an element that has id ='MTG_INSTR$2'. The issue appears to be that this element only loads after some javascript is executed. Even if I wait for this element to load, when my plugin executes this line,

```
var els = document.getElementById('MTG_INSTR$2')
```

els is null. I've attached the full code below.

PS: when debugging in chrome I can see that it has the correct document and that the MTG_INSTR$2 id is within the document

manifest.json

```
{
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extensiontest",
  "version": "0.2",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","content.js"]
  }
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "start" ) {
         start();
             }
      }
    );

    function start(){       
        var els = document.getElementById('#MTG_INSTR$2'); //first sign of the issue, els is always left null
        console.log(els);
        alert("started");
    }
```

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#button1', function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "start"});
   });
});
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src = "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="button1" type=button value=clickme></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the hash in :

```
var els = document.getElementById('#MTG_INSTR$2');
```

Good way would be :

```
var els = document.getElementById('MTG_INSTR$2');
```

Comment: Also, i notice popup.js is not included in content scripts, that makes it load only when you open the popup, and probably is only reading the content in your popup.html file